# Apartment descriptions in France. Exposure explanation

Tags: france

Does anyone know what 'Exposition: 5' means in French apartment descriptions? Does it have to do with the orientation?

Comment: As a french native speaker, this 'Exposition:5' is meaningless. 'Exposition' in the context of apartment descriptions means in which direction are the windows or the building (ie North, South, ...).

Comment: If that was 'S' instead of '5', then this could make sense as something like 'south-facing'.

Answer (score 2):

It was certainly an "S" and not a "5", and meant that the apartment is facing south, which means it gets a lot of light. Nothing else makes sense.